# Toggle localstorage item in Svelte

Tags: javascript, local-storage, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

new to Svelte so excuse the little knowledge.

I am attempting to save a `localStorage` item `on:click` and toggle it when clicked again.
Currently, the item is added to localStorage but on a second click, it is not removed. If you refresh the page and click the item is removed but I would like this not to be necessary.

*Onclick event*

```
<button on:click={dyslexiaFriendlyFont} class="primaryBtn" >Dyslexia friendly font</button>
```

*Toggle Handling*

```
  let _ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken = localStorage.getItem(
    '_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken'
  )

  function dyslexiaFriendlyFont() {
    console.log('clicked')
    if (_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken == undefined) {
      localStorage.setItem('_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken', 'true')
      body.classList.add('_ac_dyslexiaFont')
    } else (_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken == "true") {
      localStorage.removeItem('_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken')
      body.classList.toggle('_ac_dyslexiaFont')
    }
  }
```

Could someone please help me here? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is eveluated once when you open the page

```
  let _ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken = localStorage.getItem(
    '_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken'
  )
```

When you click the first time, you write `'true'` to localStorage, but the variable `_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken` stays the same and so when you click the second time you'll land again in `if (_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken == undefined)`

`_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken` is `null`, but `undefined == null // true` since you have only two equal signs ~ it's possible to simply check `if(_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken)` or `if(!_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken)` to check if the value is truthy or falsy
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

So to switch between the `if(){}else{}`  change `_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken` in addition to writing to local storage

Here's your modified example which also adds the class if the token is set in localStorage on opening the page

```
<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'

    let _ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken = localStorage.getItem('_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken') // null or 'true'
    console.log(_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken)

    let body

    onMount(() => {
        body = document.querySelector('body')
        if (_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken) body.classList.add('_ac_dyslexiaFont')
    })

    function dyslexiaFriendlyFont() {
        if (_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken) {
            console.log('remove token')
            _ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken = null
            localStorage.removeItem('_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken')
            body.classList.remove('_ac_dyslexiaFont')
        } else {
            console.log('add token')
            _ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken = 'true'
            localStorage.setItem('_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken', 'true')
            body.classList.add('_ac_dyslexiaFont')
        }
    }
</script>

<button on:click={dyslexiaFriendlyFont} class="primaryBtn">Dyslexia friendly font</button>

<style>
    :global(._ac_dyslexiaFont) {
        background: teal;
    }
</style>
```

(`_ac_dyslexiaFriendlyFontToken` set as `'true'` or `null` like the values from localStorage. Would also work with booleans `true` and `false` Not sure if there's a convention to follow...)

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Everything working as it should now :)

Comment: @kukihi Great :) If the question is answered, you can mark it as so by clicking on the checkmark to the left